# $(window).scroll does not fire event when using multiple pages in a html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, floating-action-button

I would like to implement floating action button into long pages.
It works well when I write simple html page.
But, it does not work properly when I write multiple pages into one html. It does not fire $(window).scroll event after jumping between inner pages. I will show simplified source codes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>Floating Action Button Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var offset = 220;
    var duration = 500;
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
            jQuery('.back-to-top').fadeIn(duration);
        } else {
            jQuery('.back-to-top').fadeOut(duration);
        }
    });

    jQuery('.back-to-top').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, duration);
        return false;
    })
});
</script>

<!-- PAGEA -->

<section data-role="page" id="pagea">
<header data-role="header">
<h1>PAGE A</h1>
<div class="ui-btn-right">
<a id="logoutButton" class="headerButton" href="#pageb" data-role="button">PAGE B</a>
</div>
</header>

<div data-role="content">
<h1>CONTENT</h1>
<h2>AAA</h2>
<h2>BBB</h2>
<h2>CCC</h2>
<h2>DDD</h2>
<h2>EEE</h2>
<h2>FFF</h2>
<h2>HHH</h2>
<h2>III</h2>
<h2>JJJ</h2>
<h2>KKK</h2>
<h2>LLL</h2>
<h2>MMM</h2>
<h2>NNN</h2>
<h2>OOO</h2>
<h2>PPP</h2>
<h2>QQQ</h2>
<h2>RRR</h2>
<h2>SSS</h2>
<h2>TTT</h2>
</div><!--main-->

<footer data-role="footer">
FOOTER
</footer>

</section>

<!-- PAGEB -->

<section data-role="page" id="pageb">
<header data-role="header">
<h1>INDEX</h1>
<div class="ui-btn-right">
<a id="logoutButton" class="headerButton" href="#pagea" data-role="button">PAGE A</a>
</div>
</header>

<div data-role="content">
<h1>CONTENT</h1>
<h2>aaa</h2>
<h2>bbb</h2>
<h2>ccc</h2>
<h2>ddd</h2>
<h2>eee</h2>
<h2>fff</h2>
<h2>ggg</h2>
<h2>hhh</h2>
<h2>iii</h2>
<h2>jjj</h2>
<h2>kkk</h2>
<h2>lll</h2>
<h2>mmm</h2>
<h2>nnn</h2>
<h2>ooo</h2>
<h2>ppp</h2>
<h2>qqq</h2>
<h2>rrr</h2>
<h2>sss</h2>
</div><!--main-->

<footer data-role="footer">
FOOTER
</footer>

</section>

<!-- ############################################################## -->

<a href="#" class="back-to-top">Back To Top</a>

</body>
<style>
.back-to-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 2em;
    right: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.80);
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 1em;
   display: none;
}

.back-to-top:hover {
    background-color: rgba(135, 135, 135, 0.50);
}
</style>
</html>
```

When load this page, scroll event is normally fired and floating action button is displayed. But, after jumping to 'Page B', scroll event will not be fired anymore.

Could somebody tell me what is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i have check it and the problem you have got that 
jQuery(window).scroll don't work when you click on Page B because the location is changes and simply to fix this change jQuery(window).scroll to jQuery(document).scroll and it will work

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var offset = 220;
var duration = 500;
//here you should change jQuery(window) to jQuery(document) like this
jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
        jQuery('.back-to-top').fadeIn(duration);
    } else {
        jQuery('.back-to-top').fadeOut(duration);
    }
});



jQuery('.back-to-top').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, duration);
    return false;
})
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it works well. Appreciated.